# Java force-tooling-api pom dependency is not available anymore

Tags: java

Trying to add the "Force Tooling API" dependency to my java project from the https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api/force-tooling-api/32.0.0 repo:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api/force-tooling-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.force.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>force-tooling-api</artifactId>
    <version>32.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

There is a note regarding this dependency on the mavens page:

> Note: this artifact is located at Spring Plugins repository
> (https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/)

okay - adding a custom repo to my pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-repo</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

but now it says "401 Unauthorized":

> com.force.api:force-tooling-api:pom:32.0.0 failed to transfer from
> https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/ during a previous attempt.
> This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not
> reattempted until the update interval of spring-repo has elapsed or
> updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact
> com.force.api:force-tooling-api:pom:32.0.0 from/to spring-repo
> (https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/): authentication failed for
> https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/force/api/force-tooling-api/32.0.0/force-tooling-api-32.0.0.pom,
> status: 401 Unauthorized

after googling a bit, I found at https://spring.io/blog/2022/12/14/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-january-2023 that:

> Anonymous clients will no longer be able to download Spring Releases
> (including released plugins) from https://repo.spring.io, instead they
> should be sourced from Maven Central. Virtual repositories will NOT
> resolve snapshots and milestones anonymously. Only /snapshot and
> /milestone will resolve anonymously.

But how do I get the tooling-api dependency now? Are there any other official public repositories that would allow me to download the dependency?

Changing the repo URL to https://repo.spring.io/snapshot / or https://repo.spring.io/milestone/ doesn't help:
Could not find artifact com.force.api:force-tooling-api:jar:32.0.0 in spring-repo (https://repo.spring.io/milestone/)

Comment: Heading off some comments I can just see this getting. Yes, this is Salesforce-related. Not many people here are going to be using Java/Maven (so OP may not get much in the way of answers), but it is definitely Salesforce-related and _is on-topic_ here.

Comment: Also, v32 is quite old (Salesforce is killing api versions <= 30 in June 2025). Wonder why it's only the tooling api that's gotten the short end of the stick here. All the other API artifacts have been kept up to date.

Comment: The only Java binding still officially supported by SF for core APIs is [wsc](https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc). Most of what wsc supports are SOAP-based APIs. Tooling is available via SOAP.

Comment: Yeah, it weird to see v32 in 2024, and all other libs v60, but it is what it is...